# How to pass env variables from python script to gitlab ci with requests?

Tags: python, gitlab-ci

Need to pass env variable from python script to gitlab ci pipeline. Tried

```
responce = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/trigger/pipeline", data={'token': 'token', 'ref': 'branch', 'variables': [{'key': 'MR_ID', 'value': 'VALUE'}])

responce = requests.post("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/trigger/pipeline", data={'token': 'token', 'ref': 'branch', {variables': [{'key': 'MR_ID', 'value': 'VALUE'}]})
```

Getting {"error":"variables is invalid"} all the time.

Here is what documentation says: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#create-a-new-pipeline

Could anybody provide real working python example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you misunderstand what the `data` parameter is in a `requests.post`. If you have a look at [the docs](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) you can see, that the information from `data` will be delivered in the body.

What you want to fulfill the gitlab API is the `params` parameter of requests.

`params` will encode the `data` in the URL as query parameter like this:

```
requests.post("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/pipeline", params={"MR_ID": "VALUE"});
```

So you have to put your `variables` in the `params` parameter and the other information you have in `data` at the right place (like token in the header etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the variable in the following way:

```
import requests
url = "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/{project_id}/trigger/pipeline"
data = {'token': 'token', 'ref': 'branch', 'variables[MR_ID]': 'VALUE'}
response = requests.posts(url, data=data}
```